# TypeInitializationException accessing MonoGame GraphicsAdapter.Adapters, could not load type 'SharpDX.Rectangle'

Tags: monogame, sharpdx

Converting VB code from XNA 3.1 to MonoGame.

Any attempt to access class `GraphicsAdapter` throws the exception below. For example, trying to enumerate GraphicsAdapters. On this line:

```
For Each adapter As GraphicsAdapter In GraphicsAdapter.Adapters
```

Result is an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter' threw an exception.
  Source=MonoGame.Framework
  TypeName=Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter.get_Adapters()
       at ...my code...
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233054
       Message=Could not load type 'SharpDX.Rectangle' from assembly 'SharpDX, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1'.
       Source=MonoGame.Framework
       TypeName=SharpDX.Rectangle
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter.CreateAdapter(Adapter1 device, Output monitor)
            at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter.PlatformInitializeAdapters(ReadOnlyCollection`1& adapters)
            at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter..cctor()
```

Note the inner exception:

```
Could not load type 'SharpDX.Rectangle' from assembly 'SharpDX, ...Version=4.0.1.0, ...
```

The project references these assemblies (among others):

- MonoGame.Framework version=3.6.0.1625
  from NuGet "MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX", file
  packages\MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX.3.6.0.1625\lib\net40\MonoGame.Framework.dll
- SharpDX version=4.0.1.0
- SharpDX.Direct2D1 version=4.0.1.0
- SharpDX.Direct3D9 version=4.0.1.0
- SharpDX.DXGI version=4.0.1.0
- SharpDX.Mathematics version=4.0.1.0

So I don't see why it would fail this way.

What could be wrong? Not compatible with this SharpDX version?

NOTE: These are all up-to-date packages from NuGet, in Visual Studio 2015. Targeting .Net 4.5.2.

---

**UPDATE**

To prove it isn't a problem with SharpDX, I put this line before that GraphicsAdapter line:

```
Dim testRect As SharpDX.Rectangle = New Rectangle()
```

This successfully created `testRect`. No Exception until attempt to access `GraphicsAdapter`.  Also tried all the other Shared (static) properties of `GraphicsAdapter`, such as `GraphicsAdapter.DefaultDevice`. Any one fails with same exception.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your stack-trace?  The part you trimmed out and replaced with "..My Code.." could give important context, such as where in the application life-cycle you are accessing the adapters.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - its in the edit history. I removed it after determining it was not relevant to a TypeInitializationError, whose InnerException is a failure to load a Type from SharpDX, that has already been loaded (see my UPDATE). I've also tested access to all other shared fields of GraphicsAdapter, confirming it is not specific to the list of adapters. And tested it after the application had "settled down", by putting the access on a button event.

Comment: I am now getting help [on MonoGame forum](http://community.monogame.net/t/typeinitializationexception-accessing-graphicsadapter-adapters-could-not-load-type-sharpdx-rectangle/9803). Once problem is solved, I will duplicate that as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question to MonoGame forums:
http://community.monogame.net/t/solved-typeinitializationexception-accessing-graphicsadapter-adapters-could-not-load-type-sharpdx-rectangle/9803

**Cause of problem:**

Current release of MonoGame.Framework for WindowsDX (Windows OS + DirectX drivers), 3.6.0.1625 is built against SharpDX 2.6.3, and is not compatible with more recent SharpDX versions.

**(Interim) Solution:**

The developer branch of MonoGame does target the current SharpDX. Builds can be obtained from MonoGame's teamcity (free registration required).
Tested MonoGame.Framework build 3.7.0.994; it worked with SharpDX 4.0.1:
http://teamcity.monogame.net/viewLog.html?buildId=56483&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=MonoGame_PackagingWindows

That build installs most SharpDX dlls to
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows`
However, `SharpDX.Mathematics.dll` is currently missing,
so I still install SharpDX from NuGet, rather than using those.

---

**Standard location for MonoGame releases:**
(look for at least **3.7**, which is not there yet, as I write this):
http://www.monogame.net/downloads/

(If instead of *NuGet packages for MonoGame and SharpDX*, I had *downloaded MonoGame 3.6 installer* and used *its* version of SharpDX dlls at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows`, then I would not have had this incompatibility. However, that was not recent enough SharpDX for my purposes.  This should be resolved by release of MonoGame 3.7)